# Char conversion is wrong?

Tags: arduino

I  have this:

```
 Serial.write(charBuf[0]);  //gives 5
 String data(charBuf);
 Serial.write(data);   //gives nothing (space)
```

first is prints 5 , second prints nothing. What am i missing? is it has to do with NULL terminated stuff?

This is how the buffer is being created:

```
int len=1;
char charBuf[len];
for(int k=ACT_THRESH;k<ACT_THRESH+len;k++)
{
    charBuf[k-ACT_THRESH]= EEPROM.read(k);
}
```

Comment: You have to add a final `\0` to have a valid `String`

Comment: where i creates it ? how in my example i am adding it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int len = 1;
int str_len = 0;
char charBuf[16];
for(int k = ACT_THRESH; k < ACT_THRESH + len && str_len < sizeof(charBuf); k++)
{
    charBuf[str_len++]= EEPROM.read(k);
}
charBuf[str_len] = '\0';
```

But I don't get the goal of the loop if `len = 1`

Comment: here the len is 1 just for a test. btw, in you answer you have to set len to be 2 not 1 , am i wrong ?

Comment: oh i see. but why 16 ? how did you get to a size of 16 bytes ?

Comment: no `charBuf` size is 16, the length of the string is `str_len`

Comment: `charBuf` is on the stack, you can use the size you want, just use a size big enough to store your data. Prefer 8 multiple to have a correct alignment.

Comment: ok thanks , one more,just out of curiosity, why did you change my way- and added a new integer? cant we just charBuf[k-ACT_THRESH] ?

Comment: also, for a buffer that holds the char 'a', do we need a buffer with length of 1? (+null terminator so its becomes 2 ? )

Comment: If you need a string you need and extra space for the final `\0` for a string of length `len` you need a buffer of size `len + 1` . I use a new because I don't get the meaning of `len`. Another solution is to fill the buffer with `0` using  `memset` for example

Comment: ok great thanks, but why do we add only 1 to the array ? the '/0'  are 2 chars, you have the " / " and the "0"   ?  why not len+2 ?

Comment: `'\0'` is the null char this is not `'0'`